# implementing function in a class causes error: member reference base type 'ifstream (string)' is not a structure or union

Tags: c++, ifstream

I'm trying to implement a function that reads a column of data from a text file and stores it in a vector, which works. However when I try to implement it inside of a class I'm clearly missing some step. This causes the terminal to output the following message:

Outout for

```
error: member reference base type
      'ifstream (string)' is not a structure or union
                ...

error: member reference base type
      'ifstream (string)' is not a structure or union
                while(!file.eof()){
                ..
error: invalid operands to binary
      expression ('ifstream (*)(string)' and 'double')
                        file >> line;
```

In my class I try to implement the following function to be used with it's data members:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fstream> 

using namespace std;

class spectData{
public:
    vector<double> x, y, z;
    vector< int> A;
    vector<double> readVector(string){
        ifstream file(string);
        double line;
        vector<double> a;

        if(file.fail()){
            cout << "-----------------\n";
            cout << "Input file error!\n";
        }
        while(!file.eof()){
            file >> line;
            a.push_back(line);
        }
        return a;
    };
};
```

Any hint as to why this wouldn't work inside a function, but would inside main function?

Comment: what else do you expect from `ifstream file(string);` where `string` is a type name, not parameter name?

Comment: Another good reason not to use `using namespace std;`

Comment: Also, you should *not* be doing [`while(!file.eof())`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)

Comment: `#include <stdio.h>` should be `#include <cstdio>` in C++.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issues in this code are numerous, including:

- Failing to include `<string>`. Don't rely on another header to do that for you.
- Invalid parameter naming (as in, you have none; remember parameters are `Type name`).
- Building on the mistake from above, `ifstream file(string);` therefore declares a *function* called `file` that takes a `string` parameter and returns an `ifstream` (which is impossible, as that class does not support copy construction, but does support *move* construction, not that it matters here).
- Using `.eof()` as a loop condition, which is nearly *always* wrong (and this is no exception). [**Read this for why.**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)
- Minor: Reinventing the iterative read operation. `std::istream_iterator` provides this functionality for you, and should be exploited.
- Minor: blanketing this with `using namespace std;`

For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream> 
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

class spectate
{
public:
    std::vector<double> x, y, z;
    std::vector< int> A;

    std::vector<double> readVector(const std::string& fname)
    {
        std::vector<double> res;

        std::ifstream file(fname);
        if(!file)
        {
            std::cout << "-----------------\n";
            std::cout << "Input file error!\n";
        }
        else
        {   // dump the file of doubles into your vector
            std::copy(std::istream_iterator<double>(file),
                      std::istream_iterator<double>(),
                      std::back_inserter(res));
        }
        return res;
    }
};
```

Truth be told, you can forego much of that if error reporting is handled by the caller (such as an empty file, vector, etc), at which point that entire member can be reduced to simply:

```
std::vector<double> readVector(const std::string& fname)
{
    std::ifstream file(fname);
    return std::vector<double> {
        std::istream_iterator<double>(file),
        std::istream_iterator<double>() };
}
```

It somewhat brings into question whether the function is truly even needed at all. The caller could just as easily have done this entirely on their side.

Answer (score 6):

```
using namespace std;  
...
vector<double> readVector(string){
//                        ~~~~~~^
//                        missing parameter name
    ifstream file(string);
//                ~~~~~^
//                whoops, type name aka std::string instead of parameter name
```

What your `ifstream file(string);` currently does, it declares a function `file` that takes by value a parameter of the `std::string` type and returns the `std::ifstream` instance. Hence the error you get. What you probably meant to do is to supply a path parameter to your `file`'s constructor:

```
vector<double> readVector(const string& path){
//                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
//                        parameter name
    ifstream file(path.c_str());
//                ~~~^ ~~~~~~^
//
```

Answer (score 2):

`string` is a typename that you've pulled in inadvertently via the `using namespace std`. As a result, `file` is not what you intended - it is a function taking a `std::string` and returning an `std::ifstream`. Avoid `using namespace std` except in very controlled scopes - definitely not in header files.

Answer (score 1):

`#include <vector>`
does includes `std::string`. After `using namespace std;` `std::string` becomes type `string` so you cant use `string` as variable name because it is a type.

You should write `using std::vector;` instead of `using namespace std;`

Comment: And you shouldn't rely on implementation-dependent header inclusion.